# NTDS quota using PowerShell

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0, powershell-4.0

How to query AD NTDS quota maximum configured and how much each user used from PowerShell? I know this can be achieved from Windows command `dsget`. I would like to get PowerShell command.

Answer (score 1):

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory;
Get-ADObject -SearchBase (Get-ADDomain).QuotasContainer -Filter * -Properties msDS-QuotaEffective, msDS-QuotaUsed;
```

Taken from [this pdf](http://blogs.technet.com/cfs-file.ashx/__key/communityserver-components-postattachments/00-03-54-23-12/PowerShell-Cmd-Line-Conversion-Guide-AD.pdf) from [this blog](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/ashleymcglone/2013/01/02/free-download-cmd-to-powershell-guide-for-ad/).

Consider also looking at the properties `msDS-DefaultQuota` and `msDS-TopQuotaUsage`.

Comment: I have seen this. But this will not retrieve the users current quota usage.

Comment: Did you look at the properties `msDS-QuotaEffective` and `msDS-QuotaUsed`?  I've added that to the statement above.

Comment: Yes i have checked, but i couldn't find  msDS-QuotaUsed for a user object.

Comment: Hm.  Not sure then.  Unfortunately, the domain I have access to does not use quotas at all so I'm not able to test.